# Creating a Generics collection to which one cannot add the specified type

Tags: java, generics

I understand the PECS concept and why the below `add()` compile and don't compile:

```
List<? super ClassCastException> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new ClassCastException()); // OK
list.add(new Exception()); // Does not compile
```

But shouldn't the below be illegal then? Why not? (specifying the super type that we can't add when instantiating)

```
List<? super ClassCastException> list2 = new ArrayList<Exception>(); // Compiles
                                                          ^
```

Comment: Because List<Exception> is a sub type of List<? super ClassCastException>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine the reason why the first piece of code is illegal:

```
List<? super ClassCastException> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Exception()); // Does not compile
```

`list` is of type `List<? super ClassCastException>` i.e. a list of unknown type that is a parent of `ClassCastException`. You can't put an `Exception` in there because what if the list is actually a list of `RuntimeExcept`? `RuntimeException` is also a parent class of `ClassCastException` isn't it? *And you certainly can't put an `Exception` in a list of `RuntimeException`!*

However, this is different:

```
List<? super ClassCastException> list2 = new ArrayList<Exception>();
```

What can you assign to `list2`? `list2` is declared as a list of unknown type that is a parent of `ClassCastException`. Any kind of list that fits the criteria can be assigned.

"But there are other parent classes of `ClassCastException` though!" you say. Well, yes there are, but in an assignment statement, do we care what the original value of `list2` actually is? No. If `list2` was originally an `ArrayList<RuntimeException>`, fine. We can still assign an `ArrayList<Exception>`. There is no contradiction here. See the italicised in the first paragraph? That's the contradiction that occurs if you try to put an `Exception` in a list of `? super ClassCastException`. You can't point out anything wrong about this assignment statement though.

Comment: Understood, adding to a bounded List vs. assigning to a bounded reference.